Error when I try add image in ctkinter in pyinstaller exe
I can't display images in a customtkinter interface when I create an executable with pyinstaller. Everything works when I run it normally through VS Code, but it doesn't work in the pyinstaller executable.
Code
logoLight = 'arquivos/logoLight.png'
logoDark = 'arquivos/logoDark.png'

tamanho = Image.open(logoDark).size
self.img = ctk.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open(logoDark), light_image=Image.open(logoLight), 
    size=(int(tamanho[0]/2), int(tamanho[1]/2)))
        
self.label_img = ctk.CTkLabel(self.frame_conteudo, text=None, image=self.img)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 950, in <module>
File "app.py", line 15, in __init__
File "app.py", line 47, in telaInicial
File "app.py", line 31, in definicaoImagemJanelaPrincipal
File "PIL\Image.py", line 3277, in open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\path'

Pyinstaller command
pyinstaller --onefile -w app.py
I was expecting that it works, but it doesn't work

Study PyInstaller Run-time Information.

you may need path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'file.dat')) to get correct path to file. And you may have to add images manually to PyInstaller using special file .spec
